# calculate Matrix \inverse with Weka

Tags: java, matrix, weka

can some explain breifly to me how to calculate the inverse of a given n by n matrix using the Weka system. I am suppose to use it for a java project and  I am trying to figure out how to go about it.

Any suggestion is greatly welcomed.

my second question is that I have checked the website and looks like the requirements for Weka 3 is  a java 1.6 JVM but I have a Java 1.7 JVM on my machine is there a work around it so that I can use iWeka 3 on my machine despite the 1.6JVM requirements..

thanks all.

Comment: Java 1.7 is backwards compatible. You shouldn't have any problem running 1.6 bytecodes

Comment: ok thanks will try that but do you have any suggestions on tutorials about how to use the Weka systems.